# Why can't my device connect to my home Wi-Fi, but is able to connect to others?

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-ace

<sup>Another user asked a [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/9957/16265) that covers the same grounds as my issue, but it has no answers and very few details about what was tried.</sup>

My router is an [DVG-G5402SP](http://www.dlink.co.th/products/?idproduct=366) using the 802.11g standard and the security type WPA/WPA2 PSK.

[image: D-Link DVG-G5402SP]

When I try to connect the Wi-Fi in my phone both manually and auto, it presents a message mentioning `out of range`, even though I'm sitting right beside the router.

I really did a lot of changes such as changing the ssid of my router and the security type but nothing seem to work.

I'm able to connect to others Wi-Fi available on my area, just can't connect to my home Wi-Fi.

**My question is:**
How can I deal with this situation as to successfully connect to my home Wi-Fi?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! You are probably referring to [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/9957/7574)?

Comment: Strongly recommend looking at: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29291/wifi-connection-dropping

Comment: Have you looked at (both for Galaxy Ace): http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22356/wifi-doesnt-stay-connected **OR** http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8869/why-does-wifi-show-an-error-whenever-i-try-to-reconnect-galaxy-ace

Comment: Try using a different channel.

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy to know, but:

2 posibilities:

- Check that the IP address configuration is correct.
- [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) is properly configured, if needed.
- If you can't connect, try to change the security of your Wi-Fi...
- Check if the [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) access is enabled.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

My tablet was connected to my home wifi and then stopped. Sitting in the same room as my router it reports the connection as out of range. I am using an old router set as an access point and everything else (android phones and laptops) connect to it just fine. To correct the problem I went in and reset the channel on the AP from 13 to 11  and VOILA instant connection.

Comment: That's in fact an interesting explanation, as channels above 11 are IMHO "restricted" in some areas. There might be a reason for that :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite old D-Link WiFi router.

It likely needs to be either replaced or a firmware update.

---

It may need to be re-configured to use different channels, to be compatible with the **Samsung Galaxy Ace**.